# How to deploy to custom server after success CI in docker environment?

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I already did CI, but now I want to deploy to my server. My server is the same machine where I do CI, but I do CI in docker-executor. So I can't have acces to server folders to update production.
There is my script:

```
image: node:9.11.2

cache:
  paths:
     - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

stages:
  - test  
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    #here I want to go to /home/projectFolder and make git pull, npm i, npm start
    # but I can't beause I run CI in docker-environment which hasn't acces to my server's dirictories.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should consider using gitlab auto cicd ( or use it as a base to customize if you dont want to use kubernetes)

You have multiple way to do so but the simplest way should be to use an alpine image and
 - install ssh (if necessary)
 - load your private ssh key ( from pipeline secrets)
-  run your npm commands through ssh.

The cleanest way would be :
-  generating adding a valid Dockerfile to your project
- adding docker image generation for each commit on master (in your pipeline)
- Adding docker rm running image (in your pipeline)
- Adding docker run the newly generated  image (in your pipeline) (by sharing your docker volume)
- Make nginx redirect to your container.

I can give more detailed advice depending on what you decide to do.

Hoping i helped.